# Error while merging dex archives Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to solve this error

> app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug' which caused by 'java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives

I have tried to enable the multidex but still it's not solving any problem ? Any thoughts on this ? Thank you so much

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.cklai.o2om"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'



implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'


//Firebase
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'


//FirebasUI
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.3'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:3.2.2'

//Google play service
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'


//Design
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Thread Error

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)



  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\0.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\1.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\2.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\3.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\4.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\5.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\6.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\7.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\8.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\9.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\10.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\11.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\12.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\13.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\14.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\15.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\16.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\17.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\18.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\19.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\20.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\21.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\22.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\23.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\24.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\25.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\26.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\27.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\28.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\29.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\30.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\31.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\32.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\33.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\34.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\35.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\36.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\37.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\38.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\39.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\40.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\41.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\42.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\43.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\44.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\45.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\46.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\47.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\48.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\51.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\52.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\53.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\54.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\55.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\56.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\57.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\58.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\59.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\60.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\61.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\62.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\63.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\64.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\65.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\66.jar, C:\Users\cklai\Desktop\Facebook Feed UI\O2Om\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\67.jar
Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
Program type already present: android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel
    at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:230)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    ... 33 more
```

Comment: I had kind of the same issue a while back, especially with firebase dependecies. I noticed while using the latest-version of the sdk(that is 16+) resulted in some error, using the most stable version = 15.0.0 worked well for me. Also ensure the versions match, e.g firebase auth and firebase firestore should use the same version

Comment: Thanks for your help, it seems like the reason is because firebase auth ,firebase Firestore , firebase ui and Firestore ui are not same version.